# Propagation phenomena in cables

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, frequency, cables, fft

I have came across the propagation phenomena that takes place when we have a source and a load connected through a cable. We have an impedance mismatch and hence a propagation phenomena.
So what I did, is that I wanted to account for the parameters of the cables but in frequency domain. I did two measurements: open and short circuit and studied the circuit in frequency domain. The circuit looks like this:

[image]

However, I have a problem. In paper, the input voltage is trapezoidal (output of a DC-DC converter made with a transistor), but in reality it is already subject to the propagation phenomena, so resonances are reflected at both ends of the cable.

My questions are:

1. Why is it that my input voltage is not enforced and easily modified by the current of the load when measured?
2. Is my reasoning concerning accounting for the presence of the cable through its high frequency characterization using and impedance analyzer correct? I do an ifft later to compute the Voutput. If not, what am I doing wrong?

My DC-DC converter looks like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *We have an impedance mismatch and hence a propagation phenomena* That is not a correct deduction! Just because you have an impedance mismatch doesn't mean this has anything to do with wave propagation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Question 1 is contradictory; if you want an enforced source (i.e. a solid voltage output) then you don't want it easily modified by load current. And anyway, there are no clear details of the source so how could this be answered? What do you mean by a "propagation phenomena"? Do you mean a reflection?

Comment: @Andyaka should an enforced voltage source be modified by the load current? Yes, reflection phenomena

Comment: @Andyaka maybe there is something wrong with my measurement setup, that's why I don't get why the enforced voltage source is trapezoidal when I use a resistance as a load, but contains resonance once I insert a cable+load

Comment: I read it like this: *not (enforced* **and** *easily modified by the current of the load)*. I think you know that your voltage source is weak anyway. But, you need to show it's circuit to give clarity.

Comment: Cutting to the chase, you can't analyse a transmission line properly by using short and open circuit impedances <-- it just won't be useful. A reflection (not a reflection phenomena) is a propagation phenomena. You need to understand what the characteristic impedance of a cable means. You can't get anywhere useful with t-line analysis without it.

Comment: @Andyaka I added the circuit to the question

Comment: @Wallflower there's nothing to elaborate. You claim "from A follows B", but that's not correct: When A, then sometimes B, sometimes not B. (A: "We have an impedance mismatch", B: "This involves propagation")

Comment: That's not a DC/DC converter.

Comment: Your addition contradicts the 2 port cable you show in the earlier diagram. Now this may sound petty but, t-line analysis requires ultra rigorous accuracy.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, but that's it. This is self-contradictionary in the text in multiple places, the nomenclature is wrong, the schematics don't match; none of the text in the pictures is legible. Voting to close this as unclear.

Comment: @MarcusMüller voting to close the question will not help me understand what I am doing wrong...

Comment: What you appear to be doing wrong is approaching t-line theory from a faulty standpoint. You are assuming that a cable can be reduced to two impedances and this is miles away from what is correct. Your question comes over as "surely it can't be as hard as those books" and, "here's my take on things". I know that may be argued but, that's how it comes over to me having read your question several times now (looking for a small nugget of truth to make a formal answer). In other words you are asserting things that are wrong and to roll-back those assertions would strip my patience to the limit.

Comment: @Wallflower I'm afraid the fact that you won't learn anything but the many things we wrote in the comments will not make the question salvageable :( So, you really need to go back. Get a good book on transmission line theory. Open it on page 1 – and work from thereon; you just have too many things mixed up here, and basically every statement you make takes *pages* to correct; trying to even start answering this makes no sense; we'd just writing a *worse* book.

Comment: You should start by reading about characteristic impedance and propagation delay (not easy stuff btw).

Comment: Yes, I agree – and I should have said this more clearly: This stuff is actually hard! Took me quite a while to understand it when I was sitting in the lecture teaching me about it, and much of what I understand today also only came to me long after I had written the accompanying exam; it's hard to build up a correct intuition for this, and easy to jump to incorrect conclusions (my B.Sc. grade in that subject can tell you a tale about that). But: nearly everybody in my semester at some point passed that exam, and understood the basics of transmission lines. It just *really* takes some work.

Comment: @Wallflower Question: what is your cable? Is it a coaxial cable, a length of wire, twisted pair, ...? What length is your cable? One thought that comes to mind is you may be seeing the effects of the inductance of the cable which means you need to place a bypass capacitor from the the load's power input to ground. 1 cm of wire length can cause issues with high current and fast edges on switching power supplies due to inductance.

Comment: @qrk Thanks for reaching out. I have a coaxial cable does not exceed 1m, and I confused the used chopper for a DC-DC converter -my bad-.

Comment: @qrk Also the Vdc = 15 V the current is kept low with the very small chosen value of the duty cycle, to avoid destroying components